# Trying to use functions from one JS file in another file, in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have content scripts activated like,

```
content_scripts: [
    {
        matches: some_pattern,
        scripts: [
                 script1,
                 script2
                 ]
    },
    .....
]
```

I want to use function from script1 in script2, but it gives me an error saying the function name is undefined. If someone could shed light on how I can modularly write my code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The functions should be global or be a property of a [global variable](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+global+variable). Otherwise you'll need to use a compiler/bundler.

Answer (score 0):

Within `content_scripts`, I believe that scripts should be formatted to `js` and `css`. An example being:

```
content_scripts: [
    {
        matches: some_pattern,
        js: [
                 script1,
                 script2
                 ]
    },
    .....
]
```

These are then injected into the page in order of the array. So `script2` should be able to access the functions of `script1`.

This is shown here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts